# Add basic controls eg label and text box to people picker with react in Sharepoint Online

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online

I have the code below to render a people picker in Sharepoint online using the React Framework.  How do I add basic controls such as labels, textboxes and buttons.

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
    import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';

    import { Label } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Label';
    import { TextField } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField';
    import { getId } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Utilities';


    export interface IPnPPeoplePickerWebPartProps {
      description: string;
    }

    export default class PnPPeoplePickerWebPart extends 
      BaseClientSideWebPart<IPnPPeoplePickerWebPartProps> {

      public render(): void {
       const element: React.ReactElement<IPnPPeoplePickerProps > = React.createElement(
        PnPPeoplePicker,
          {
          description: this.properties.description,
          context: this.context
          }
       );

      ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);

      }
```

Here is the code for a label.  I just don't know where to insert it.  It doesn't work in the render method.

```
export const LabelBasicExample = () => {
  // Use getId() to ensure that the ID is unique on the page.
  // (It's also okay to use a plain string without getId() and manually ensure uniqueness.)
  const textFieldId = getId('anInput');

      return (
        <div>
          <Label>I'm a Label</Label>
          <Label disabled={true}>I'm a disabled Label</Label>
          <Label required={true}>I'm a required Label</Label>
          <Label htmlFor={textFieldId}>A Label for An Input</Label>
          <TextField id={textFieldId} />
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you create a new react component to wrap your components.
Also, your render() method in the first block of code is a little strange... Look at the second block, there's no call to ReactDom.render.

Usually that call is only on my index.tsx file. Something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

So inside the App.tsx (in the component render method) I would do something like this:

```
  return (
  <div>
    <mycomponent1/>
    <mycomponent2/>
    <pnpcomponent/>
... many other components...
  </div>)
```